# Leopard gecko in a pine terrarium

Tags: leopard-geckos, terrariums

I was thinking about getting a leopard gecko and i was reading that certain types of wood are toxic for reptiles.

I understand that having pine or cedar shavings as substrate is a big nono, but what about a pine structure?

I have an already-built terrarium made of what i think is pine, will it be still dangerous even if it's not shavings?

Comment: Is the pine shaved or cut in any areas? Or is it possibly sealed with something?

Comment: @SerenaT It's cut on the sides and it has 2 holes. I was planning on sealing it